How to use SHAP explainer for explainability of a deep learning model with multimodal input (image and tabular data)?
I am trying to run SHAP explainer on a deep learning model trained on image and tabular data.
import shap

model_obj = load_model(model_path)

# Initialize the SHAP maskers for each modality
image_masker = shap.maskers.Image("data", shape=images.shape[1:])
tabular_masker = shap.maskers.Partition(numerical_features)

# Initialize the SHAP explainer with appropriate maskers
explainer = shap.Explainer(model_obj, data=[images, numerical_features], masker=[image_masker, tabular_masker])

# Calculate SHAP values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values([images, numerical_features])

# Visualize the explanations
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, [images, numerical_features])

The approach below keeps throwing the following AttributeError.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

I am not sure if SHAP supports explainability for multimodal inputs, as I have not found any documentation or examples related to such problems.
How can I resolve this. Also, please suggests any other methods to explain such models.
